# HTML - How can I set the width of a floating element to 100% of its parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
body{
   margin:0;
  }
  #navbar{
   background-color:red;
   height:70px;
   
   width:80%;
   margin:auto;
  }
  #search{
   width:100%;
  }
  #element1{
   height: 100%;
   float:left;
   background-color:green;
   display: table;
  }
  #element2{
      height: 100%;
   float:left;
   background-color:yellow;
   display: table;
  }
  .v_center{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border-style: solid;
   width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HEAD>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
 <div id="navbar">
  <!--<img src="http://www.findwatchdeals.com/media/logo.png" width="100px" height="50px"/>
  <input type="search" id="search"/> -->
  <div id="element1" >
   <div class="v_center">
    test
   </div>
  </div>
  <div  id="element2" >
   <div class="v_center">
    <input type="search" id=#search/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both;"/>
 </div>
</BODY
</HTML>
```

This is the result:
[image]

How can I make #element2 with a width of 100%, like this:
[image]

I think I need to get rid of the 'float:left', but without it, they don't align next to eachother. Can someone help me?

Comment: `#element1 {width:10%;} #element2 {width:90%;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the best way to do it. use flex instead of table.

check your HTML, you've defined ID in a wrong way.
should be like this:

```
<input type="search" id="search">
```

I have edited your snippet. please check

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box; //add this
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
}

#element1 {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  //display: table;
  //width: 20%;
}

#element2 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  //display: table;
  //width: 80%;
  
}

.v_center {
  //display: table-cell;
  //vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HEAD>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="navbar">
    <!--<img src="http://www.findwatchdeals.com/media/logo.png" width="100px" height="50px"/>
  <input type="search" id="search"/> -->
    <div id="element1">
      <div class="v_center">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="element2">
      <div class="v_center">
        <input type="search" id="search">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </div>
</BODY </HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem is that the elements aren't aligned at the middle vertically.

Comment: check again. i don't know why but the comments were creating problem. i have updated the snippet

Answer (score 1):

use `width` for each element

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
}

#element1 {
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  display: table;
}

#element2 {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table;
}

.v_center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
}
.v_center #search{width:100%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="navbar">
    <!--<img src="http://www.findwatchdeals.com/media/logo.png" width="100px" height="50px"/>
  <input type="search" id="search"/> -->
    <div id="element1">
      <div class="v_center">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="element2">
      <div class="v_center">
        <input type="search" id="search" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </div>
</BODY> </HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the searchbar to be 100% also?

Comment: Why drops #element2 out of #navbar at a certain width of the browser view?